# ¿Cómo puedo quitar la URI de la URL en PHP?

Tags: php, apache, url

¿Como puedo remover la URI que obtengo con **$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]**?

En mi página, al cargar, muestra en la URL **prueba.com**, hasta ahí todo bien, ahora lo que necesito es que al cargar el módulo que necesito entonces me muestra lo siguiente: **prueba.com/modulo**

La cuestión es que con PHP tengo que remover la URI para obtener **prueba.com** y al hacer un **echo** a **$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]** me debe mostrar  **//** y no el nombre del **HOST** ésto como si el módulo(**prueba.com/modulo**) sea tratado como **prueba.com**

Espero me puedan ayudar.

**NOTA: Si necesito obtener la URI, pero en el proceso que estoy haciendo necesito removerla en ciertos segmentos**

Comment: _NOTA: Si necesito obtener la URI, pero en el proceso que estoy haciendo necesito removerla en ciertos segmentos_ No se entiende, no adivino lo que quieres hacer. ¿La respuesta de @aldanux responde a la pregunta? Si no, ¿puedes releer tu pregunta y editarla, de forma que quede más claro lo que quieres?

Comment: Dices que estás trabajando con REQUEST_URI, pero quieres que `prueba.com/modulo` se convierta en `prueba.com` sin usar el nombre del HOST. Creo que la descripción es inconsistente. Veamos. ¿Quieres una función que recibiendo el REQUEST_URI te devuelva `/` o te devuelva `HOST . "/" . REQUEST_URI`?

Answer (score 0):

Con `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` obtienes el nombre del host del servidor, ej.: `www.domain.com`

> **Nota**: Bajo Apache 2, se debe establecer UseCanonicalName = On y ServerName. De lo contrario, este valor refleja el nombre del host proporcionado por el cliente, el cual se puede burlar. No es seguro depender de este valor en contextos que necesiten seguridad.

[+ info](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php)